# Is there a way to create Window partitions ordered by event times in Apache Spark?

Tags: apache-spark

I'm very new to Apache Spark and am struggling with a problem. I need to find the first event for **continuous** events on the same channel/eventtype. To illustrate what I mean, with this data:

```
|eventtype|channel|      eventtime|
+---------+-------+---------------
      Play|  1|2020-08-19 01:51:09|
      Play|  1|2020-08-19 01:54:09|
      Live|  1|2020-08-19 02:23:53|
      Live|  2|2020-08-19 07:13:34|
      Play|  1|2020-08-19 09:59:49|
      Play|  1|2020-08-19 22:29:33|
      Live|  2|2020-08-19 22:29:37|
```

I need to transform it to this:

```
|eventtype|channel|      eventtime|
+---------+-------+---------------
      Play|  1|2020-08-19 01:51:09|
      Live|  1|2020-08-19 02:23:53|
      Live|  2|2020-08-19 07:13:34|
      Play|  1|2020-08-19 09:59:49|
      Live|  2|2020-08-19 22:29:37|
```

My understanding of:

```
Window.partitionBy("channel", "eventtype").orderBy("eventtime")
```

is that it would group all of the distinct channel/eventtypes into partitions and then grabbing the first row would produce this:

```
|eventtype|channel|      eventtime|
+---------+-------+---------------
      Play|  1|2020-08-19 01:51:09|
      Live|  1|2020-08-19 02:23:53|
      Live|  2|2020-08-19 07:13:34|
```

Is there a way to use Window functions or something else to accomplish this in Spark?

Comment: ` need to find the first event for continuous events on the same channel.` you mean channel and eventtype ? not just channel, right ?

Comment: Also, your result dataframe is confusing ! you want the first event chronologically ? if yes, shouldn't (Live,1) give this 2020-08-19 02:23:53

Comment: hey thanks for the clarifying questions. i technically do need it by eventtype and channel but didnt want to complicate the question further so i only asked about continuous events on the same channel. I should have left the eventtype out of the data entirely.

Comment: Yes :)  would've been good to have eventtype and channel in question, to keep coherence between question and wanted results

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up using something like:

```
withColumn("prevchannel", lag("channel",1).over(window) 
and
where(startPrevValues("channel") =!= startPrevValues("prevchannel"))
```

to find all the events where the channel changed

Answer (score 1):

Your assessment is correct that partitioning the dataset by "channel" and "eventtype" would not produce the wanted output since the given `time-series` dataset must be processed chronologically by "eventtime" in an uncluttered fashion.  Below is one approach to produce the wanted result:

```scala
val df = Seq(
  ("Play", 1, "2020-08-19 01:51:09"),
  ("Play", 1, "2020-08-19 01:54:09"),
  ("Live", 1, "2020-08-19 02:23:53"),
  ("Live", 2, "2020-08-19 07:13:34"),
  ("Play", 1, "2020-08-19 09:59:49"),
  ("Play", 1, "2020-08-19 22:29:33"),
  ("Live", 2, "2020-08-19 22:29:37")
).toDF("eventtype", "channel", "eventtime")

import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window

val win = Window.orderBy("eventtime")
val keyCols = Seq(col("channel"), col("eventtype"))

df.
  withColumn("row_num", row_number.over(win)).
  withColumn("prev_keycols", lag(struct(keyCols: _*), 1).over(win)).
  where($"row_num" === 1 || struct(keyCols: _*) =!= $"prev_keycols").
  show
/*
+---------+-------+-------------------+-------+------------+
|eventtype|channel|          eventtime|row_num|prev_keycols|
+---------+-------+-------------------+-------+------------+
|     Play|      1|2020-08-19 01:51:09|      1|        null|
|     Live|      1|2020-08-19 02:23:53|      3|   {1, Play}|
|     Live|      2|2020-08-19 07:13:34|      4|   {1, Live}|
|     Play|      1|2020-08-19 09:59:49|      5|   {2, Live}|
|     Live|      2|2020-08-19 22:29:37|      7|   {1, Play}|
+---------+-------+-------------------+-------+------------+
*/
```

The intermediary columns are left in the output for references.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `window` function with `row_number` and `filter` as below

```
val window = Window.partitionBy("eventtype", "channel").orderBy("eventtime")

df.withColumn("rank", row_number().over(window))
  .filter($"rank" === 1)
  .drop("rank")
  .show(false)
```

Output:

```
+---------+-------+-------------------+
|eventtype|channel|eventtime          |
+---------+-------+-------------------+
|Live     |1      |2020-08-19 02:23:53|
|Play     |1      |2020-08-19 01:51:09|
|Play     |2      |2020-08-19 07:54:53|
|Live     |2      |2020-08-19 07:13:34|
|Play     |3      |2020-08-19 09:59:48|
+---------+-------+-------------------+
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, it's extremely close but not quite what I was looking for. The partitions don't have a sense of being continuous. For example, later events that are channel 1 will also be grouped into the first rows, but they need to be their own rows.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you want to keep first eventtime per channel and eventtype here.

The Window Function in spark returns the rank of rows within a window.

You can use partitions indeed as you said

```
    val result_df = df
     .withColumn("rank", rank.over(Window.partitionBy("eventtype","channel").orderBy("eventtype")
     .filter(col("rank")===1)
```